# Error with data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having problem with datagrid view. I have attached an image with the code & error message. I want to know the reason of this error. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the LINQ query. just set the list as the DataSource. There is no need to set the DataMember in this case.

```
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Products> productList = new List<Products>()
        {
            new Products{ProductName = "P1", ProductPrice = 56, Category = "c1"},
            new Products{ProductName = "P2", ProductPrice = 36, Category = "c1"}    
        };

        //var p = from s in productList select s;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = productList;
        //dataGridView1.DataMember = p.ToString();
    }
```

**EDIT**

LINQ query is returning `IEnumerable`; however the DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that implements one of the following interfaces:  IList, IListSource, IBindingList, and  IBindingListView. So you will need to call `ToList()` to your LINQ result. Read more about this on this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)

However in your case doing this is same as setting `productList` as DataSource (I mean the results will be the same, as there is no sorting or grouping involved in the LINQ query).

If you want to play with LINQ, try this out (your list will be ordered by `ProductPrice` in ascending order)

```
   var p = from s in productList orderby s.ProductPrice select s;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = p.ToList();
```

Comment: I know that, but actually I'm doing this to practice linq, I want to see the result of my different query like grouping,orderby & where. So I need to use the linq. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `DataMember` simply call the bind method `dataGridView1.DataBind()`. As stated by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datamember.aspx) the `DataMember` is used for the following:

> Gets or sets the name of the list or table in the data source for which the DataGridView is displaying data.

Comment: I didn't find the DataBind method, I'm working on winforms, I think this method is available for web apps. I also add reference to system.web assembly,but still not getting the method. Anything else you can suggest? Thanks